# Content Negotiation on Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat6, content-negotiation, multiviews

I'm trying to get my Tomcat to use pretty URLs, similar to Apache's MultiViews option. I tried using AJP to proxy Tomcat to Apache, but the .htaccess file is still ignored.
What are my options for Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Filter. Let it listen on `/*` and *redirect* any unfriendly URL to an friendly URL and *forward* any friendly URL to an unfriendly URL. A good opensource example is [Tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) which behaves almost exactly like Apache's `mod_rewrite`.

If this concerns a brand new webapplication which is yet to be developed, then a better way is to adopt a MVC framework which supports RESTFul URL's, like [Spring MVC](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/). Or maybe homegrow a front controller servlet which makes use of [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) to determine the pathinfo.